# SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Anyone can refactor java code to kotlin code ?

this is my code

FoodListAdapter.kt

```
class FoodListAdapter: StatelessSection(SectionParameters.builder()
    .itemResourceId(R.layout.content_food_list)
    .headerResourceId(R.layout.header_food_list)
    .build()) {

    val itemList = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3 ,4)

    override fun getContentItemsTotal(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindItemViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        val itemHolder = holder as MyItemViewHolder

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(itemList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemViewHolder(view: View?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyItemViewHolder(view!!)
    }
}

class MyItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    lateinit var tvItem: TextView
    init {
        tvItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem) as TextView
    }
}
```

FoodListActivity.kt

```
class FoodActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var context: Context? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list)

    context = this
    val sectionAdapter = SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter()

// Add your Sections
        sectionAdapter.addSection(FoodListAdapter())

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.foodList) as RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(context))
        recyclerView.adapter(sectionAdapter)
    }
}
```

I got a problem is 
"Expression 'adapter' of type 'RecyclerView.Adapter<(raw) RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"
after recyclerView.adapter(sectionAdapter) 
Someone please guide me to fix this.
sorry i not good at english

Answer (score 1):

```
class FoodListAdapter(val itemList): StatelessSection(SectionParameters.builder()
    .itemResourceId(R.layout.content_food_list)
    .headerResourceId(R.layout.header_food_list)
    .build()) {

    override fun getContentItemsTotal(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindItemViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemHolder = holder as MyItemViewHolder
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(itemList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemViewHolder(view: View?): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyItemViewHolder(view!!)
    }
}

class MyItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    internal val tvItem: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem)
}
```

And for your activity you don't need context variable Activity extends Context

```
class FoodActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list)

    val sectionAdapter = SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter()

        val itemList = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3 ,4)
        sectionAdapter.addSection(FoodListAdapter(itemList))

        val recyclerView:RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.foodList)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = sectionAdapter
    }
}
```

as @CampbellMG mentioned you need to either use `recyclerView.adapter = sectionAdapter` or `recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter)`

`recyclerView.adapter=sectionAdapter` is more idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a class property as a function

In Java you would set the adapter with:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter)
```

In Kotlin this looks like:

```
recyclerView.adapter = sectionAdapter
```

Have a look [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) for more information.